# My System crashed after I build GTK+-3.12 from source

Tags: ubuntu, compilation, gtk3, gnome

First , my operating system is Ubuntu Gnome 14.04.1, and the version of the GTK is 3.12.2, the source files are all downloaded in [Gnome official website](http://www.gtk.org/download/linux.php).

In this afternoon, I try to build `gtk+3.12` from the source code. There are lots of depandency problem, and  I have spent a lot of time to solve it.

After finish all the operation, the GTK+-3.14 has successfully install. But then some problem happened. **After finished it, my windows , the icon, the frame became very ugly.** Then I try to reboot the computer. But, when the system booted, it showed:

> The system is running in low-grafic mode. Your screen, graphics card, and input device settings could not be detected correctly. You will need to configure these yourself.

After click the `next` bottom, the system **can't boot and these's only a mounse in the screen.** The TTY can enter.

Please help me, why my computer crashed? And **How to build the GTK+-3 in Ubuntu ?**

---

There are the `depandency problem` and the library I install to solve the problem:

- glib-2.40.0

  **problem**

  > configure: error: *** Working zlib library and headers not found ***

  **solve:**    `sudo apt-get install ruby`
      `sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev`

  **problem**

  > configure: error: Package requirements (libffi >= 3.0.0) were not met:

  **solve**    `sudo apt-get install libffi-dev`

---

- atk-2.12.0

  no

---

- gdk-pixbuf-2.30.8

  **problem**

  > configure: WARNING: *** TIFF loader will not be built (TIFF library not found)`

  **solve**    `sudo apt-get install libtiff4-dev`

  **problem**

  > configure: WARNING: *** PNG loader will not be built (PNG library not found)***
  >
  > configure: WARNING: *** PNG loader will not be built (PNG header file not found) ***
  >   ````

  **solve**    `sudo apt-get install libpng-dev`

---

- gobject-introspection-1.40.0

  **problem**

  > configure: error: flex not found but required

  **solve**    `sudo apt-get install flex`

  **problem**

  > configure: error: bison not found but required

  **solve**    `sudo apt-get install bison`

  **problem**

  > configure: error: Python headers not found

  **solve**    `sudo apt-get install python-dev`

---

- pango-1.36.5

  **problem**

  > configure: error: *** Could not enable any backends.

  **solve**    `sudo apt-get install libcairo-dev`
       `sudo apt-get install libcairomm-1.0-dev`

  > What's more,  I also install  `HarfBuzz` . I download the source file `http://www.freedesktop.org/software/harfbuzz/release/harfbuzz-0.9.22.tar.bz2` and compile it.

---

- gtk+-3.12.2

  **problem**

  > configure: error: *** XInput2 extension not found. Check 'config.log' for more details.

  **solve**    `sudo apt-get install libXi-dev`

  **problem**

  > configure: error: Package requirements (atk atk-bridge-2.0) were not met:
  >
  > No package 'atk-bridge-2.0' found
  >
  > Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you installed software in a non-standard prefix.
  >
  > Alternatively, you may set the environment variables ATK_CFLAGS and ATK_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
  >   See the pkg-config man page for more details.

  **solve**    `sudo apt-get install libatk-bridge2.0-dev`

  **problem**

  > Couldn't find include 'GdkPixbuf-2.0.gir' (search path: ['../gdk', '/usr/share/gnome/gir-1.0', '/usr/local/share/gir-1.0', '/usr/share/gir-1.0', '/usr/local/share/gir-1.0', '/usr/share/gir-1.0', '/usr/local/share/gir-1.0'])
  >   make[4]: *** [Gdk-3.0.gir] Error 1
  >   make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/simowce/GTK/gtk+-3.12.2/gdk'
  >   make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
  >   make[3]: Leaving directory`/home/simowce/GTK/gtk+-3.12.2/gdk'
  >   make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
  >   make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/simowce/GTK/gtk+-3.12.2/gdk'
  >   make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
  >   make[1]: Leaving directory`/home/simowce/GTK/gtk+-3.12.2'
  >   make: *** [all] Error 2`

  **solve**    `sudo apt-get install gobject-introspection`

  > What' s more, I also install `gdk-pixbuf` from the source file from [HERE](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/gdk-pixbuf/2.30/gdk-pixbuf-2.30.4.tar.xz).

  **problem**

  > Couldn't find include 'Atk-1.0.gir'

  **solve**

  > To solve this problem, I download `ATK-2.14.0` from `http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/atk/2.14/atk-2.14.0.tar.xz`.
  >
  > Then, I build it by using the listed command:
  >
  > `./configure --prefix=/usr
  >   make
  >   sudo amek install`

Comment: Never, ever, install self-built software into `/usr` unless you are really sure of what you are doing. Use a tool like [JHBuild](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/Jhbuild?action=show&redirect=Jhbuild) to build GTK.

Comment: Can you tell me how to build GTK by using `JHBuild` ? Thanks~

Comment: There's a tutorial on that page that I linked above.